# Ring of rational power series

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be any commutative ring with 1. A power series $f\in A[[t]]$ is called *rational* if we can find a $g\in A[t]$ such that $fg\in A[t]$. It is clear that the set of rational power series forms a ring which I call $R_A$.

> I am looking for references giving properties of $R_A$ in terms of properties of $A$. For example is it true that $R_A$ is noetherian if $A$ is noetherian?

If $A$ is a field this should be ok because $R_A=A(t)$ which is a field.

> Other properties I would like to know are flatness and integrality of $R_A$.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/68710/rational-power-series

Comment: sorry this does not answer to my question.

Comment: If $A$ is a field then $R_A$ should be the subring of $A (t)$ consisting of those rational functions whose denominator does _not_ vanish at 0. Or perhaps you mean to ask about Laurent series?

Comment: A remark: when $A$ is a domain, it seems that you are considering the ring $A[[t]] \cap A(t)$ (viewed inside $A((t)))$)